# PHP Localization Files

Tags: php, file, localization, translation

I am implementing language files for my PHP application. I am using constants to define each word that I want to have translation for. I put a folder in the root of my application with files like en.php, fr.php, de.php, it.php etc. The translations are for form elements and error messages to display in their respective language. The language can be selected by clicking on a flag on top of the page.

What I'm not sure about is if the language file that holds all the defined words should be a single file or broken down into many, so I can load just what I need for each page. My app is getting quite large and it seems like a bad idea to load a giant PHP file.

Having single files located in a single location makes loading them simple but I'm not sure if this is the way to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with gettext but I want to have control of the translated text and so I shy away from external services.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about gettext being an external service. You can provide the translation files yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my suggestion would be use the divide and conquer approach obviously if you can achieve such a modularity that you are including only page/request specific language files than it would improve the response time

Answer (score 0):

I too agree to divide it, create file as your needs appear down the way.

Since  you want text file this is a **very primitive just for demonstration** example with text files. However I think going with static classes could look a bit more organized than simple constants.

**./index.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();   
///////////////////////////////// LANGUAGE /////////////////////////////////// 
if(!isset($_SESSION['langid']))/*This will run only once*/
    $_SESSION['langid']="en";//persistent store
if(isset($_GET['langid'])) 
    $_SESSION['langid']=$_GET['langid'];//persistent store 

 /*** define the   path ***/  
define ('__LANG_PATH',  'C:/wamp/www/lang/lang/'.$_SESSION['langid'].'/');

echo"
<a href=index.php?langid=en>English</a><br>
<a href=index.php?langid=fr>French</a><br><br>";

include('history.php');
?>
```

**./history.php**

```
<?PHP
    include __LANG_PATH.'txtHistory.inc';
    echo txtArticle::$body_title;
    echo '<br>';
    echo txtArticle::$history_article
?>
```

**./lang/en/txtHistory.inc**

```
<?PHP
 class txtArticle 
{
    public static $body_title="Welcome to history page..";  
    public static $history_article=
"Based at RAF Medmenham, a country house on the banks of the 
Thames, the Central Interpretation Unit (CIU) was established in 
April 1941. ."; 
} 
?>
```

**./lang/fr/txtHistory.inc**

```
<?PHP
 class txtArticle 
{
    public static $body_title="Bienvenue à la page d'histoire..";   
    public static $history_article=
"Basé à la RAF Medmenham, une maison de campagne sur les
leur travail, les opérations de l'OPC et la guerre, qui incluse guider 
les raids de la Dam Busters, a été largement méconnus jusqu'à présent.
";  
} 
?>
```